# Reordering the paragraphs in a text file using python

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

I have a python code that produces the output text file in a word document. This output file is being produced in a for loop. The text file being produced is a summary text of an article. The output looks something like this:

```
Results:

<....summarized text.....
........................>

Methods:

<.....summarized text.....
.........................>

Conclusions:

<.....summarized text....
........................>

Background:

<.....summarized text.....
.........................>

Methods:

<.....summarized text.....
.........................>

Results:

<....summarized text.....
........................>


Conclusions:

<.....summarized text....
........................>

Background:

<.....summarized text.....
.........................>
```

Whereas I want the output text file in the following format:

```
Background:

<.....summarized text.....
.........................>

Methods:

<.....summarized text.....
.........................>

Results:

<....summarized text.....
........................>

Conclusions:

<.....summarized text....
........................>

Background:

<.....summarized text.....
.........................>

Methods:

<.....summarized text.....
.........................>

Results:

<....summarized text.....
........................>

Conclusions:

<.....summarized text....
........................>
```

How can this be achieved using python?

Comment: Are you referring to the order of the output? Both the output files look the same. Could you be more specific?

Comment: yes, the paragraphs need to be reordered.